# Best way to compare multiple fields of objects in java?

Tags: java

I want to compare 2 object as same class,i want to konw What's the difference between two filed of the object,
for example,

```
public class Person{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  ......
}

Person person1 = new Person();
person1.setName("jim");
person2.setage(12);

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.setName("jason");
person2.setage(14);
```

public Map compare(person1,person2)?

tell me name is different and age is different?

Comment: Use reflection to check every field and compare it in both objects, then put the contents in a `Map`.

Comment: Is there any other way if i dont't use reflection

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Unless of course there is a `getName()` of `getAge()` method that we haven't seen yet :) Are you sure you cannot create these methods, @SummerZeng ?

Comment: You really wouldn't want to call every method manually.. Reflection is the way to go when it's about meta questions like this. I'll add a sample in some time when none have done so, I'm in the middle of something now.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't do what you're saying, write the method and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method to do it with Reflection:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.name = "Jack";
        person1.age = 18;
        person1.favoriteSuperhero = "Superman";

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.name = "Jack";
        person2.age = 20;
        person2.favoriteSuperhero = "Superman";

        Map<String, List<Object>> uncommonTraits = getUncommonTraits(person1, person2);
        for(Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : uncommonTraits.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":\t" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, List<Object>> getUncommonTraits(Person p1, Person p2) {
        Map<String, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(Field field : Person.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            try {
                if(!(field.get(p1).equals(field.get(p2)))){
                    result.put(field.getName(), new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(field.get(p1), field.get(p2))));
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String favoriteSuperhero;
}
```

Output:

> age:  [18, 20]

This is very resistant to changes: if you add a field to your `Person` class, you won't have to change anything. It is also a bazillion times less redundant than manually checking each field.

I have used `public` fields for ease of use.

Comment: Should remove try/catch and check field null when do compare.

Comment: You cannot remove the try/catch. It's either that or throws. The fields can be null, a `null` value is caught by the `instanceof` requirement in every `Equals()` implementation. It will just return `false` as it should.

Comment: My mistake.  I thought field. get doesn't throw checked exception. Do you think we should move try/catch to out side for statement?

Comment: @Loc: that's entirely up to you. The chances of these two exceptions appearing is very low, it doesn't really matter.